# Poincaré plane and Logistic Map

Tags: classical-mechanics, chaos-theory, non-linear-systems, complex-systems

How can we draw Poincaré plane and phase portrait for the Logistic Map for different parameter values?

Answer (score 2):

For dynamical systems in general, you typically simulate the dynamics in a computer - for instance, numerically integrating differential equations, or iterating a map - and then you can analyze your data. The tools mentioned in the question are primarily used for visualizing the solutions:

- a **phase portrait** is usually the plot of one or more trajectories in the system's phase space (which is its state space, i.e., a space where each point denotes a different system state);
- a [**Poincaré plot**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_plot) is (for 1-D systems) a plot of, e.g., $x_{n+1}$ against $x_n$, i.e., for a trajectory $x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3, ...$ the Poincaré plot will be 2-D with points $(x_0,x_1), (x_1,x_2), (x_2,x_3), ...$;
- don't mix up the **Poincaré plot** with the similarly named **Poincaré map**, which displays trajectories at a *lower* dimensionality than that of the system, by means of a section of its phase space (for details see answers [1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/141539/75633) and [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/399008/75633), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_map), ...). As for logistic map, it's 1-D, so it has a 0-D Poincaré section/map - not that useful for visualization purposes.

> How can we draw Poincare plane and phase portrait to Logistic Map for different parameter values?

1. choose the value of the parameter $r$;
2. choose an initial condition for the state variable $x$: that's $x_{n=0}$;
3. obtain $x_0$'s trajectory by iterating $x_{n+1}=rx_n(1-x_n)$.

Now, with this trajectory in hands, you can obtain plots (by hand or software) such as the Poincaré plot for $r=4$ displayed in the Logistic Map's Wikipedia [entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map):

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c1/Logistic_map_scatterplots_large.png]

For a different parameter value, you'd obtain a different plot. A 3-D plot with axes $r$, $x_{n+1}$, and $x_n$ would also be a possibility.

The logistical phase portrait is simply a segment of line, $x_n \in [0,1]$. It can show which parts of it are more densely populated by trajectories, and a 2-D plot of $\{x_n\}$ as a function of the parameter $r$ is known as a [**bifurcation diagram**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifurcation_diagram). Again from [Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/50/Logistic_Bifurcation_map_High_Resolution.png):

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/50/Logistic_Bifurcation_map_High_Resolution.png]

Also worth of mention, for 1-D maps at least, is the [**cobweb plot**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobweb_plot), which is essentially a graphical representation of the iteration process that is very useful for gaining an intuition about the process. Wikipedia [examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobweb_plot) use precisely the logistic map:

[image]
[image]